# Overlapping a UL tag on a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I am not so pro in CSS. I tried whatever I can in my knowledge. I want to display the UL menu over any content below. In this example its "Hello".
But currently "Hello" shifts down when the menu is opened. I tried examples of other SO questions but they are not working. You can find the complete code at:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#demo_box').popmenu({
    'controller': 'true',
    'width': '100%',
    'background': '#800000',
    'focusColor': 'black',
    'borderRadius': '10px',
    'top': '0',
    'left': '0',
    'iconSize': '50px'
  });
})
```

```css
.demo_li {
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Popup-Menu-Plugin-Pop-Menu/jquery.popmenu.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo_box">
  <div id="pop_ctrl"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
  <ul id="demo_ul">
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
      <div>Home</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></div>
      <div>Cloud</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div>
      <div>settings</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
      <div>E-mail</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
      <div>Clock</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></div>
      <div>Files</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></div>
      <div>Favourites</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></div>
      <div>Mobile</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></div>
      <div>Exit</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
Hello
```

Comment: You write about a 'menu', but the CSS that you posted on the jsfiddle page shows no styling for a menu. Have you looked at the `position` property in CSS? This allows you to remove an element (such as your menu) from the normal flow of the page.

Comment: Styling is done in the JavaScript. Please check External Resources of the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` with `top`

```
#demo_ul{
    position:absolute !important;
    top:0;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#demo_box').popmenu({
    'controller': 'true',
    'width': '100%',
    'background': '#800000',
    'focusColor': 'black',
    'borderRadius': '10px',
    'top': '0',
    'left': '0',
    'iconSize': '50px'
  });
})
```

```css
.demo_li {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
}

#demo_ul {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Popup-Menu-Plugin-Pop-Menu/jquery.popmenu.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo_box">
  <div id="pop_ctrl"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
  <ul id="demo_ul">
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div>
      <div>Home</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></div>
      <div>Cloud</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div>
      <div>settings</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
      <div>E-mail</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
      <div>Clock</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></div>
      <div>Files</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></div>
      <div>Favourites</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></div>
      <div>Mobile</div>
    </li>
    <li class="demo_li">
      <div><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i></div>
      <div>Exit</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
Hello
```

The `!important` is needed to override the `position:relative` of the `popmenu.js` plugin.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva, the fiddle in my answer is working. Or did you want something else?

Comment: I took this snapshot of your fiddle output: http://i60.tinypic.com/x23uqf.png. I want "Hello" to be hidden behind the menu. Its shifting downwards.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva, can you give me a fiddle with a red menu like that? My fiddle is working but it doesnt have the red menu

Comment: Its  the snapshot of your fiddle only. Its there in the JavaScript `'background': '#800000'`

Comment: Whoa! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. :) Update your answer so that I can mark it.